# rdflib and NCName errors

Tags: python, xml, neo4j, rdf, rdflib

*Running into errors due to NCName convention not being respected in a RDF/XML file. It is pretty clear that it isn't being respected and it is found in many spots. Is there any way around this as I don't have any control on the output file?*

---

**The basic code looks like this:**

```python
from rdflib.graph import Graph

g = Graph()

g.parse("extract.xml")
```

The error goes like this:

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
rdflib.exceptions.ParserError: file:/// . . ./extract.xml:15:1: rdf:ID value is not a valid NCName: ELK_05-09-14_10:39:59_NAME

Process finished with exit code 1
```

The offending bit is the colons found in ELK-09-14_10:39:59_NAME . There are lots of other examples in the document like this and with other issues like leading with numbers.

```
<cim:Name rdf:ID="ELK_05-09-14_10:39:59_NAME">
        <cim:Name.IdentifiedObject rdf:resource="#ELK_05-09-14_10:39:59"/>
        <cim:Name.name>SecondaryCircuit__</cim:Name.name>
</cim:Name>
```

The code is to develop into something where I can import into neo4j so if I'm going about this all wrong I welcome any other approaches.

Comment: Your source data appears to be invalid (certainly the [W3C RDF/XML Validator](http://www.w3.org/RDF/Validator/) considers it to be invalid).  You either need to fix whatever is generating the data to produce valid `rdf:ID` values or report a bug to the data provider and get the original data fixed.

Comment: Yes it is pretty clear that some of the details are invalid. I don't have much choice to how it is formatted and have to take it as is. I've taken a look at xmltodict as was suggested and Etree. Having good success with Etree with no peep about NCName validation issues. Was hopping to use rdflib as it fits the problem well, not today though.